# Python-like || and && for if in C++

Tags: c++, c++11

Is the following Python-like construct slower in C++?

```
bool_stuff[i] || (a[i]=1);
```

compared the plain old

```
if(!bool_stuff[i])
  a[i]=1;
```

The reason is, I have the above snippet in a nested `for` loop with this being the only statement. I think the readability is greater in the former case, but shall use the latter only if the former is not safe or if it is slow.

Comment: This is almost certainly premature optimization. Why don't you benchmark it and see if that's actually the slow part of your code?

Comment: As for readability, you want to change `a[i]` if `bool_stuff[i]` is true. The second version sounds much closer to your actual intent.

Comment: I don't see how it's Python-like. Besides, wouldn't `a || b = c` parse as `(a || b) = c` due to `||` having higher precedence than `=`?

Comment: Have you tried to compile `bool_stuff[i] || a[i]=1;`? Spoiler: it will not, because `=` has the least priority among the operators used. And besides, the construction is not idiomatic in C++, so I'd use the variant with `if` anyway.

Comment: `prog.cpp:8:24: error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment`

Comment: Sorry, it compiles now. The edited version is the intended question

Answer (score 0):

[They compile to the same thing](https://godbolt.org/z/bJbCra) (If you use any optimisation above `-O0` in gcc, and probably in other compilers).

Other disadvantages of the first method is that the expression on the right has to be convertible to a `bool` (Calling `operator bool` if it has side effects for no reason), and, if `operator||` is overloaded, it will not actually short circuit.

The `if` statement is much more readable and the same speed.

Comment: The example given by the OP does not compile.  And the example you linked to is something else again.

Comment: @Peter The OP was just missing a pair of brackets. It's just a generalisation of `if (!value) action();`. In this case, `action` would be to assingning `a[i] = 1`. [Here's that demo](https://godbolt.org/z/3MQxzZ) (`call rsi` is replaced with `mov     DWORD PTR [rdx+rsi*4], 1`)

Comment: no, the OP was not missing a pair of `()`.  The OP was assuming a Python construct is valid in C++, which it is not.

Comment: @Peter That is not even valid in Python, because there are no assignment expressions in Python yet. OP was looking for the idiom common in JS: `test || action();`, which in Python would be `test or action()`, which is the same as their second snippet: `if (!test) action();`.